# Alignment of images - Not spacing out correct after float

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

Having some issues with aligning images side by side on my wordpress staging environment.

I thought this would be the easiest part of the development phase but has actually proven quite difficult.

So in a nutshell, I want to align two images together, with some space inbetween and buttons below them. Simple right?

So I did the following HTML:

```
<div class="shop-banners">
<ul>
<li>
<img src="https://www.cutepinkboutique.com/staging/wp-
content/uploads/2017/06/NoHTTPS1"> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Shop our Tops and Dresses">
</li> 
<li>
<img src="https://www.cutepinkboutique.com/staging/wp-
content/uploads/2017/06/NoHTTPS2"> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Shop Now for Boutique Clothing">
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS that I'm using:

```
.shop-banners ul {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width: 40%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; 
}

.shop-banners li {
display: inline-grid;
margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.shop-banners input {
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

This is how it looks below with the above code:[image: Images not inline]

This is all on our staging environment so I can't link the web page. I just can't figure out why this is happening. I've tried messing around with the width percentage and taken out float but no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Wrap every image in `<li>` and give `float` to it. It is not valid html to have images straight under `<ul>` element

Comment: Hi Morpheus thanks for your help. I wrapped it as follows: 

.shop-banners ul {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 width: 40%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto; 
}

.shop-banners li {
    display: inline-grid;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.shop-banners input {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

but the image still sits below one another.

Comment: It is probably because you are limiting `<ul>` to 40% width. If you need it to be that small, make sure your images are not wider than `<ul>` itself.

Answer (score 0):

That is depends on aspect ration of image , if you have two different images with different aspect ratio that if you set `width` same that you will get what you want but images resoluions will change , so try to wrap image in on `block` element set `width` property then assign `image` to `max-width:100%`

Answer (score 0):

please use Li for both sections. into the questions, it's showing only one image use CSS below

```css
.shop-banners ul {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 width: 40%
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto; 
}


li {
    display: inline-grid;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

input {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shop-banners">
<ul>
<li>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRfefpyGjtYN37nWjh0koST45Hjx9uA4TP0OKlUG81VBsKaWI7g"> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Shop our Tops and Dresses"> 
</li>
<li>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRfefpyGjtYN37nWjh0koST45Hjx9uA4TP0OKlUG81VBsKaWI7g"> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Shop Now for Boutique Clothing">
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried the above suggested code and did the following: 

.shop-banners ul {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 width: 40%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto; 
}

.shop-banners li {
    display: inline-grid;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.shop-banners input {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

but the image still sits below one another. I tried modifying the width but this made no difference.

Comment: please replace you HTML  and CSS with the HTML  and CSS into my answer

Comment: Wow. It won't let me edit your answer but I found that it went below eachother. How strange?!

Comment: why you want to edit my answer you can just copy and paste it

Comment: it was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

So for your code,

- You should use `width: 50%` for images, so that it takes half the screen width.
- For spacing between two images, use **padding** on the containing `div`.
- To arrange the button and image in the above fashion, use `flexbox` in `CSS`. By simply arranging them in rows. See below `CSS`-

I have demonstrated with `height` and `width` **responsive** for the image.

You can change that by simply changing the height of the image to an absolute value.

```css
.shop-banners {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.shop-banners__left, .shop-banners__right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
.shop-banners img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.shop-banners input {
    width: 100%;
}
.shop-banners__left {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.shop-banners__right {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shop-banners">
    <div class="shop-banners__left">
 <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/ce/4d/0c/ce4d0c6e5769b1ae0e78a09a516bce6a.jpg"> 
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Shop our Tops and Dresses"> 
    </div>
    <div class="shop-banners__right">
 <img src="http://vivaglammagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/636096742373357996142416222_fashion-beauty-tips.jpg"> 
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Shop Now for Boutique Clothing">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that I used was mainly correct, however it is best practice to encase it in

.

The major difference, was scaling down the actual image sizes within the media library of wordpress. Once I did that and modified the width percentage in css, they managed to align without issues.